# Why is std::mutex::unlock() not noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, destructor, raii

Why is `std::mutex::unlock()` not `noexept`?  For some reason the standard leaves the behavior undefined when a thread that does not own the mutex calls `unlock()` on it.  What is the justification for doing so?  Doesn't this cause `std::unique_lock` or `std::lock_guard` destructors implementations from accidentally leaking exceptions in their destructors if the function throws?

*Note* Destructors that throw - https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/destructors-that-throw/

Comment: I think it is just a consequence of the comittee's policy to apply noexcept very carefully and only where it is critical for performance and/or for realizing the basic/strong exception guarantee.

Comment: I myself have this question when dealing with exception-safety in code using mutex, specifically what does it *mean* for unlock() to throw and how client code can reasonably deal with it (particularly if used through something like unique_lock, which presumably will cause a termination if an unlock() exception actually happens in its destructor, which is fine as we'd otherwise wind up violating a post-condition). Just seems like, as a very low-level part of the library, this needs to be better specified. Compare it to std::atomic where everything is noexcept (as you'd expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say why the committee didn't make it `noexcept`. I can only point out the fact that `noexcept` is - in general - only applied explicitly to a few key functions throughout the standard library that are necessary for implementing efficient functions providing the strong exception guarantee (like `std::swap` or move constructors).

As far as `std::unique_lock` is concerned however: Its destructor IS (implicitly) `noexcept`, so if an implementation would allow unlock to throw, `unique_lock`'s destructor  would have to catch it internally.

Comment: Not really. `BasicLockable` requires `unlock()` to not throw, so if it throws all bets are off - `terminate` is actually a good option there. `unlock()` isn't `noexcept` because it's narrow contract. Trying to unlock a mutex you don't own causes UB, and an implementation might want to throw an exception (e.g., in debug mode) if it can detect it.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_lock` has a flag to indicate if it 'owns' the lock. Once you call `lock` successfully, it sets the flag. When you call `unlock`, the flag will be reset.

When the destructor is called, if it doesn't own the lock, it won't call the `unlock`.

Comment: Thanks!  That's right.  But what happens in the case of `lock_guard`?

Comment: In the constructor of `lock_guard`, it `lock` the `mutex`, i.e. the parameter of the constructor. So `lock_guard` always 'owns' the `mutex`. When it destructs, it MUST `unlock` the `mutex` it owns.